# Snowflake ; SQL compilation error: Invalid object type: 'EXTERNAL_TABLE' on GET_DDL('DATABASE', 'MyDb')

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In some Snowflake databases I can run `SELECT GET_DDL('Database', 'MyDatabase');` without problem but in another one, I get the following error message

*SQL compilation error: Invalid object type: 'EXTERNAL_TABLE'*

There might be an external defined in that database but I would still like to extract the DDL recursively on the database...

Is there any trick I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using DESCRIBE EXTERNAL TABLE which describes the virtual columns on the table.
[DESCRIBE EXTERNAL TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/desc-external-table.html#describe-external-table)

Answer (score 0):

[5.8 Release Notes - March 15-18, 2021](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/5-8-Release-Notes-March-15-18-2021)

> **GET_DDL Function: External Table Support**
>
> With this release, the [GET_DDL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl.html) function supports returning a DDL statement that can be used to recreate a specified external table.
>
> Note that currently, the GET_DDL output for a specified database or schema does not include any external tables contained in the schema.